# Sublime Linter / htmltidy not working after Mojave update

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimelinter, htmltidy

HTML linting in Sublime has stopped working since I installed Mojave.

I use an older version of SublimeLinter and SublimeLinter-html-tidy as the ignore_match function is useful for hiding 'false positives' when developing emails.

Going by the console log, both plugins appear to load successfully. I think the problem lies with HTML Tidy itself.

Here's the log:

```
startup, version: 3176 osx x64 channel: stable
executable: /Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS/Sublime Text
working dir: /
packages path: /Users/user/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages
state path: /Users/user/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Local
zip path: /Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS/Packages
zip path: /Users/user/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Installed Packages
ignored_packages: ["Vintage"]
pre session restore time: 1.05351
using gpu buffer for window
using gpu buffer for window
startup time: 1.42503
environment variables loaded using: /bin/bash -l
reloading plugin Default.arithmetic
reloading plugin Default.auto_indent_tag
reloading plugin Default.block
reloading plugin Default.colors
reloading plugin Default.comment
reloading plugin Default.convert_color_scheme
reloading plugin Default.convert_syntax
reloading plugin Default.copy_path
reloading plugin Default.delete_word
reloading plugin Default.detect_indentation
reloading plugin Default.duplicate_line
reloading plugin Default.echo
reloading plugin Default.exec
reloading plugin Default.fold
reloading plugin Default.font
reloading plugin Default.goto_line
reloading plugin Default.history_list
reloading plugin Default.indentation
reloading plugin Default.install_package_control
reloading plugin Default.kill_ring
reloading plugin Default.mark
reloading plugin Default.new_templates
reloading plugin Default.open_context_url
reloading plugin Default.open_in_browser
reloading plugin Default.pane
reloading plugin Default.paragraph
reloading plugin Default.paste_from_history
reloading plugin Default.profile
reloading plugin Default.quick_panel
reloading plugin Default.rename
reloading plugin Default.run_syntax_tests
reloading plugin Default.save_on_focus_lost
reloading plugin Default.scroll
reloading plugin Default.set_unsaved_view_name
reloading plugin Default.settings
reloading plugin Default.show_scope_name
reloading plugin Default.side_bar
reloading plugin Default.sort
reloading plugin Default.swap_line
reloading plugin Default.switch_file
reloading plugin Default.symbol
reloading plugin Default.transform
reloading plugin Default.transpose
reloading plugin Default.trim_trailing_white_space
reloading plugin Default.ui
reloading plugin CSS.css_completions
reloading plugin Diff.diff
reloading plugin HTML.encode_html_entities
reloading plugin HTML.html_completions
reloading plugin ShellScript.ShellScript
reloading plugin 0_package_control_loader.00-package_control
reloading plugin 0_package_control_loader.01-pygments
reloading plugin 0_package_control_loader.50-backrefs
reloading plugin 0_package_control_loader.50-markupsafe
reloading plugin 0_package_control_loader.50-pymdownx
reloading plugin 0_package_control_loader.50-python-markdown
reloading plugin 0_package_control_loader.50-pyyaml
reloading plugin 0_package_control_loader.51-python-jinja2
reloading plugin 0_package_control_loader.55-mdpopups
reloading plugin BracketHighlighter.bh_core
reloading plugin BracketHighlighter.bh_logging
reloading plugin BracketHighlighter.bh_plugin
reloading plugin BracketHighlighter.bh_popup
reloading plugin BracketHighlighter.bh_regions
reloading plugin BracketHighlighter.bh_remove
reloading plugin BracketHighlighter.bh_rules
reloading plugin BracketHighlighter.bh_search
reloading plugin BracketHighlighter.bh_swapping
reloading plugin BracketHighlighter.bh_wrapping
reloading plugin BracketHighlighter.support
reloading plugin DeleteBlankLines.DeleteBlankLines
reloading plugin Emmet.emmet-plugin
reloading plugin Number King.king
reloading plugin Package Control.1_reloader
reloading plugin Package Control.2_bootstrap
reloading plugin Package Control.Package Control
reloading plugin SideBarEnhancements.SideBar
reloading plugin SideBarEnhancements.SideBarAPI
reloading plugin SideBarEnhancements.SideBarDefaultDisable
reloading plugin HTML-CSS-JS Prettify.HTMLPrettify
reloading plugin SublimeLinter.commands
reloading plugin SublimeLinter.sublimelinter
reloading plugin SublimeLinter-html-tidy.linter
SublimeLinter: htmltidy linter loaded 
plugins loaded
SublimeLinter: debug mode: on 
SublimeLinter: temp directory: /var/folders/f0/yk8mxx2x0gb34qdr464zxskr0000gn/T/SublimeLinter3-user 
SublimeLinter: user shell: /bin/bash 
SublimeLinter: computed PATH using /bin/bash:
/usr/bin/tidy
/usr/local/bin/csslint
/usr/local/bin/stylelint
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin

SublimeLinter: htmltidy version query: /usr/bin/tidy --version 
SublimeLinter: WARNING: no htmltidy version could be extracted from:
HTML Tidy for Mac OS X released on 31 October 2006 - Apple Inc. build 16.1

SublimeLinter:           using cmd: ['/usr/bin/tidy', '--version'], env: {'USER': 'user', 'XPC_SERVICE_NAME': '0', 'TMPDIR': '/var/folders/f0/yk8mxx2x0gb34qdr464zxskr0000gn/T/', 'PATH': '/usr/bin/tidy:/usr/local/bin/csslint:/usr/local/bin/stylelint:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin', 'SHELL': '/bin/bash', 'PYTHONIOENCODING': 'utf8', 'HOME': '/Users/user', 'XPC_FLAGS': '0x0', '__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING': '0x1F5:0x0:0x2', 'LC_CTYPE': 'en_US.UTF-8', 'LANG': 'en_US.UTF-8', 'Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render': '/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.A7fjCH4kfy/Render', 'LOGNAME': 'user', 'SSH_AUTH_SOCK': '/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.6lQRKyP2Rz/Listeners'} 
Emmet: No need to update PyV8
Package Control: No updated packages
```

Answer (score 0):

Installing the latest binary from here sorted it:
http://binaries.html-tidy.org

No need to update path in linter preferences